# Marking instance variables as transient in a class implementing serialization

Tags: java, serialization, transient

Please consider the class ArrayDeque.java

```
public class ArrayDeque<E> extends AbstractCollection<E>
                       implements Deque<E>, Cloneable, Serializable {
    transient Object[] elements; // non-private to simplify nested class access
    transient int head;
    transient int tail;
}
```

What's the purpose of implementing Serializable interface and then marking all the instance variables as transient ?

Comment: Does it have `readObject` and `writeObject` methods?

Comment: Yes it does. I got my answer. Thanks.